# Emulating Rust's Return Pattern in C#

Tags: c#

Rust has the [? operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) which returns a method if a value is `Error`. I want to recreate this behaviour in C#.

I already implemented the Rust Result pattern using an abstract `Result` class that can either be `Ok`, or `Error`. I've lived null free ever since (unless dealing with external dependencies). It also has better performance with error handling than try-catch, and is great for piping.

My main problem with this is that every time I get a Result back I have to make a little spiel that looks like this:

```
if (playlistResult is not Ok<Playlist> playlist)
{
    if (playlistResult is Error<Playlist> error)
    {
        _log.Error(error.Exception, "Error when loading playlist.");
        return Result<Playlist>.Failed("Error when loading playlist.", error.Exception);
    }
    //This is pretty much a fail-safe to keep the compiler happy.
    _log.Error("Unexpected error when loading playlist.");
    return Result<Playlist>.Failed("Unexpected error when loading playlist.");
}
//Can use playlist like a normal variable after this clause.
```

When I really wanted to slim this down I could reduce this to 2 lines:

```
if (playlistResult is not Ok<Playlist> playlist)    
    return Result<Playlist>.Failed("Unexpected error when loading playlist.");
```

This isn't great, but anything to not have nulls. That said, it's not Rust:

```
let playlist = getPlaylist()?; //The magic happens in the question-mark.
```

If the value of playlist is `Error` it returns the method with said error.

A lot can be done with extension methods, and static methods, but I'm not aware of a way to return a method with this. All I can think of are macros, which C# doesn't support either.

Something like this:

```
Ok<Playlist> playlist = playlistResult as Ok<Playlist> ?? return Result<Playlist>.Failed("Unexpected error when loading playlist.");
//Or
Ok<Playlist> playlist = playlistResult.ReturnIfError("Error when loading playlist.");
```

**[Edit]**
Because a lot seem to not understand: I already have the Result pattern. The issue is the **Return-Pattern** if the pattern-match fails.

Basic implementation of the Rust `Result` for reference (lots of helper methods removed).

```
public abstract class Result<T>
{
    public static Result<T> Success([DisallowNull] T value) =>
        value is null
            ? new Error<T>(new Exception("Value was null!"))
            : new Ok<T>(value);

    public static Result<T> Failed([DisallowNull] Exception error) =>
        new Error<T>(error);
 }

public sealed class Ok<T> : Result<T>
{
    [NotNull]
    public T Value { get; }

    internal Ok([DisallowNull] T value) =>
        Value = value;
}

public sealed class Error<T> : Result<T>
{
    public Exception Exception { get; }

    internal Error([DisallowNull] Exception error) =>
        Exception = error;
}
```

Comment: If it's just about keeping the compiler happy and the scenario shouldn't occur maybe just `throw new NotImplementedException();` ?

Comment: why not always return playlist and throw exception on error? And skip all the casting.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to tell you this, but Exceptions are really bad way of error handling (bad performance, compiler doesn't enforce catch). I only throw exceptions if I want to burn the house down.

Comment: For most cases I disagree. For example the Microsoft libs for Cosmos and Azure storage throws exception when a requested record does not exist.

Comment: Exceptions should be used in exceptional circumstances, which I would think an error loading a playlist would be.  Note: I wouldn't consider a playlist not being found to be an error.

Comment: I know, external dependencies must always be wrapped with a try-catch because, half of them throw exceptions, and the other half also throws exceptions, but doesn't signal it in the xml documentation.

Comment: It's not necessarily about the error, but the graceful handling of it. Disposing things, stopping streams, signalling other dependencies, returning a helpful (but no too detailed error) to the user, or in some cases just ignore, or retry it.

Comment: So you have two different types, one that indicates a success and one that indicates failure, right? Why not use a single type for both scenarios, with a simple bool property to indicate success instead? That would make your code easier to handle, I think. Check out my blog post about my [own implementation of `Result<T>`](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2021/03/05/handling-non-exceptional-errors-using-result-and-resultt/)

Comment: The *real* problem isn't creating the Result<T> class but exhaustive pattern matching to ensure errors are always handled. If C# had discriminated unions that would be as easy as in F#. Right now, nullable types with warnings-as-errors are as safe and as easy to use as a Result<T>

Comment: Guys, the Result implementation is not the issue, please read the question, or ask what you don't understand about it so I can improve it. I already have the Result implementation. It's been working for years at this point. The problem is returning if a condition fails.

Comment: You can achieve most of that functionality by overloading '=' operator. But can you please clarify why you need all of this?

Comment: @MayurEkbote: You can't overload the `=` operator in C#.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're trying to use a "return an error" flow design in a language with a "throw an exception" design. I get that you don't like exceptions - but if you dislike them that much, then it's probably worth just changing to a language which doesn't use them. This question is a little bit like saying "I'm using a purely-dynamically-typed language, but I really like static typing. How can I get static typing in my dynamically-typed language?" I don't believe there's any way of achieving what you want in C#.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing the point, but what do you mean when you say "returns a method"? Do you mean "exits the current method, i.e. executes an implicit `return`" or do you mean "returns an object to the caller which is a delegate type containing a reference to a method"?

Comment: Yes, which is by the way how TypeScript came to be. Anyway, I'm force to use C# because it's overall more mature than Rust, and company dependencies like Nuget injections, and also Native/C++ wrapping (which C# does better than Rust).

Comment: @JohnWu I want the fictional "ReturnIfError" method to be able to terminate ("return") the method/scope it is called in if the value is not 'Ok'.

Comment: @JonSkeet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: @MayurEkbote: Those are *conversion* operators - not the `=` operator. You can't overload the `=` operator. (Not that it would help anyway - you wouldn't be able to change the `=` operator to magically return from the calling method.)

Comment: @JonSkeet re: = very technically, yes. But you are giving multiple meanings to the same symbol anyway. It's a distinction without much of a difference. re: OP - yes. I agree with you that it is impossible to do in C# because it is different paradigm. Personally, I think the idea of magically returning on assignment is a flawed design. It is hard to read for saving a few characters of code. Reminds me of the discussion on why linq didn't have ForEach.

Comment: @MayurEkbote: Not "very technically". It's just not the same thing. A user-defined conversion operator can easily end up being used when there are no assignment operators anywhere in sight (e.g. when passing an argument to a method). Why talk about "overloading the = operator" when you definitely *can't* do that, when you can easily talk about "creating a user-defined conversion" and be correct in all ways? (I'm a big fan of taking care to use correct terminology - I've found it avoids huge amounts of confusion.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Defining standard operator overload and this conversion operator follow almost the same syntax -as does the usage. So, it is more on the overloading side than (more generic) "user defined conversion" (which can also be like System.Convert).  Simply put, = is an operator, and if you are assigning a different action to it than the base one, then you are overloading it. Just like function overloading - same name, but different actions. Anyway, I get what you are implying.

Comment: @MayurEkbote: But my point is that it doesn't change what `=` does. It changes how the RHS of the assignment operator is evaluated... *along with all kinds of other things*. Consider the code at https://gist.github.com/jskeet/2c61ce7f33056f643fe92df19ab25db2 - which is the simplest and most accurate explanation of the behavior of `Console.WriteLine(a + b);`: "There's an implicit conversion from `Value` to `int`" or "the `=` operator is overloaded, even though it doesn't appear anywhere in the statement"?

Comment: @MayurEkbote: Your way of explaining it also disagrees with [the specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#1243-operator-overloading): "In particular, it is not possible to overload member access, method invocation, or the `=`, `&&`, `||`, `??`, `?:`, `=>`, `checked`, `unchecked`, `new`, `typeof`, `default`, `as`, and `is` operators." The specification is *explicitly saying* that `=` can't be overloaded - why would you want to confuse things by claiming it can be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255175/discussion-between-mayur-ekbote-and-jon-skeet).